# What is the largest wavelength of a photon that can excite an atom in it's groundstate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, atoms

Let's assume we have an atom in it's ground state. That atom interacts with a single photon and get's exicited to a higher energy level. How large can the wavelength of the photon be?

I'm looking for wavelengths well above the 21cm hydrogen line. It obviously depends on the atom. So for which atom is this wavelength the longest? Or do you know wavelengths that are much larger than 21 cm?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422858/2451

Comment: This question is way to vague and previous research seems scarce.

Comment: @DakkVader what is vague about the question? We have an atom in it's ground state interacting with a single photon. What is the largest wavelength that can induce an excitation?

Comment: @yasalami well for starters you're aksing about specific lines associated with "an atom", what atom? which atom?

Comment: @DakkVader It could be any atom

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the deuterium atom has a 92 cm line related to ground state excitation (https://www.haystack.mit.edu/ast/science/deut/index.html)